# UBound inside Redim Preserve throws "Subscript out of range"

Tags: arrays, vba, ms-access

I want to use a dynamic array containing arbitrary number of strings. The array is filled by `if ... then` logic instead of a loop. I keep getting `Subscript out of range` error:

```vb
Dim Files() As String

If True Then
    ReDim Preserve Files(UBound(Files) + 1) ' Throws "Subscript out of range" error
    Files(UBound(Files)) = "foo.pdf"
End If

If True Then
    ReDim Preserve Files(UBound(Files) + 1)
    Files(UBound(Files)) = "bar.txt"
End If

If True Then
    ReDim Preserve Files(UBound(Files) + 1)
    Files(UBound(Files)) = "baz.jpg"
End If
```

I have a function declared like this:

```vb
Function SendFiles(Files() As String)
```

I want to get rid of this error **without using variants if possible**. I can rewrite the code but I cannot use a loop.

Comment: An unsized array has no `UBound`.

Comment: @bigben what would be the cleanest approach to handle this? I don't know in advance how many entries need to be added, there is no loop, and I am asked to use types wherever possible.

Comment: You could just use `ReDim Files(0)` before your first `If`. If you know the largest possible size at the outset you can redim to that at the outset and then cut out any unnecessary elements at the end using Preserve.

Comment: You know `ReDim Preserve` allocates an entire new array, copies elements one by one, and then updates the original reference, right? It's a pig for performance. If you have an array you expect to append to often, you should look at the [`Collection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/collection-object) type.

Comment: `If True Then` are these lines needed?  When will TRUE not be TRUE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array is not initialized at the start, and you can't `Redim Preserve` an uninitialzed array.

If you want a string array to hold a variable amount of items, possibly zero, you can start with initializing it to a zero-length array using `Split`:

```
Files = Split(vbNullString)
```

Comment: This seems to do the job. Is there a language construct to initialize an array declared as `Dim Files() As String` an array having UBound = -1?

Comment: @SalmanA No, unfortunately, there's not. You can either use `Split(vbNullString)` to get a 0-length string array, or a complicated WinAPI call to do it with a little less overhead. See [This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55123413/7296893) for more background, getting zero-length array is difficult for anything but strings.

Answer (score 1):

You could also allocate a large enough array and resize to used size afterwards. That way you have only 1 resize. Something like this:

```
Dim Files(1000) As String, i as long

If True Then
    Files(i) = "foo.pdf": i = i+1
End If

If True Then
    Files(i) = "bar.txt": i = i+1
End If

If True Then
    Files(i) = "baz.jpg": i = i+1
End If

redim preserve Files(i-1)
```